# How to delete white space using js RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to delete the white space form string using js, I found a solution that deletes ALL the white space `.replace(/\s/g,"")`, but I need to keep the space between the string.

Ex: `****example*1****` -> `example*1`

`*` space

Comment: easy you can add two white spaces or more!

Comment: Elaborating on @kapreski's comment: `.replace(/\s+/g,"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove spaces from start and end. But if you still want to use regex or your browser doesn't support trim natively then you can do this way,

```js
str = '    example 1    ';
console.log(str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""));
```